# Python Qt5 PyInstaller does not set the Icons correctly for the .EXE file

Tags: python, pyqt5, icons, pyinstaller

firstly, before people point to it, yes there is a thread of this which has basically these same symptoms, but the accepted solution as well as any other suggestions on it have not fixed my issue.

The problem is, simply put, that I can't get the exported .exe file to display the intended Icon in the Taskbar or the alt+tab menu - but it is setting it correctly in the file explorer, as well as that it is displaying the correct icon when alt+tabbing in the pyCharm Run window.

Several lines in my code set the Icon for the app (QApplication Object), the window, before or after it is shown, basically programmatically I have tried everything that came to mind. The full code is some 400 lines and is included at the bottom, sorry in advance for the shoddy work, I'm still fairly new to Python and the PyQt5 framework even more so.

As for the Icon's properties, I am at a point where i simply modified it to support any and every Size setting possible, for which i used IcoFX to export it properly. PyInstaller has verifiably grabbed the correct file, since it is successfully getting me the Icon in the file explorer. Attempting to extract an Icon from another executable and using it for my own has yielded the same result, it sets the Icon for the file explorer but not for the task bar or the alt+tab menu.

Below is also the command line I use to export the project. If there are any further informations I can provide please ask, I am going bald at this rate.
Thank you for your patience

The code:

```
    import random
import sys
import traceback

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QColor, QMouseEvent, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QSizePolicy, \
    QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint, QPropertyAnimation, QTimer, QRect

# movable title bar
class CustomTitleBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedHeight(30)  # Set the height of the title bar
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.attached = False

        self.move_bar = QWidget()
        self.move_bar.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        self.move_bar.layout = QHBoxLayout(self.move_bar)
        self.move_bar.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.move_bar.layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        self.move_bar.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: rgba(107, 4, 102, 0.5);
            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        """)

        self.attach_button = QPushButton("⇌")
        self.attach_button.setToolTip("<span style='color: white;'>Attach</span>")
        self.attach_button.setFixedSize(30, 30)
        self.attach_button.clicked.connect(parent.attach_to_bottom)
        self.attach_button.clicked.connect(self.changeAttachStatus)
        self.attach_button.setStyleSheet("""
                    QPushButton {
                        color: #FFFFFF;
                        background-color: transparent;
                        border: none;
                        border-radius: none;
                    }
                    QPushButton:hover {
                        background-color: rgba(107, 4, 102, 0.5);
                    }
                """)
        self.move_bar.layout.addWidget(self.attach_button)

        #self.collapse_button = QPushButton("▲")
        self.collapse_button = QPushButton("▼")
        self.collapse_button.setToolTip("<span style='color: white;'>Collapse/Expand</span>")
        self.collapse_button.setFixedWidth(30)
        self.collapse_button.setFixedHeight(30)
        self.collapse_button.clicked.connect(parent.toggle_button_visibility)
        self.collapse_button.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton {
                color: #FFFFFF;
                background-color: transparent;
                border: none;
                border-radius: none;
            }
            QPushButton:hover {
                background-color: rgba(107, 4, 102, 0.5);
            }
        """)
        self.move_bar.layout.addWidget(self.collapse_button)

        # Create the close button
        self.close_button = QPushButton("X")
        self.close_button.setFixedWidth(30)
        self.close_button.setFixedHeight(30)
        self.close_button.clicked.connect(parent.close)
        self.close_button.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton {
                color: #FFFFFF;
                border-top-left-radius: 0px;
                background-color: transparent;
                border: none;
            }
            QPushButton:hover {
                background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
            }
        """)
        self.move_bar.layout.addWidget(self.close_button)
        layout.addWidget(self.move_bar)

        layout.setStretch(0, 1)

        self.draggable = False
        self.drag_start_pos = QPoint()

    def changeAttachStatus(self):
        self.attached = not self.attached

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
        # if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.move_bar.rect().contains(event.pos()):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.draggable = True
            self.drag_start_pos = event.globalPos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
        if self.draggable and event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton and not self.attached:
            offset = event.globalPos() - self.drag_start_pos
            new_pos = self.window().pos() + offset

            # Get the screen's geometry
            screen_geometry = QApplication.desktop().availableGeometry()

            # Calculate the boundaries within the screen
            min_x = screen_geometry.left()
            min_y = screen_geometry.top()
            max_x = screen_geometry.right() - self.window().width()
            max_y = screen_geometry.bottom() - self.window().height()

            # Restrict the new position within the screen boundaries
            new_pos.setX(max(min(new_pos.x(), max_x), min_x))
            new_pos.setY(max(min(new_pos.y(), max_y), min_y))

            self.window().move(new_pos)
            self.drag_start_pos = event.globalPos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
        self.draggable = False

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        # Draw a border at the bottom of the title bar
        pen = QPen(QColor("#FFFFFF"))
        pen.setWidth(1)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        # painter.drawLine(0, self.height() - 1, self.width(), self.height() - 1)


class MessageWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, message, pt_size):
        super().__init__(flags=Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowTransparentForInput)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setFixedSize(1500, 150)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.container = QWidget()
        self.container.setStyleSheet("""
            QWidget {
                border: 10px solid rgba(107, 4, 102, 1);
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
        """)
        self.container.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.container)
        self.container.layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.label = QLabel(message)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setStyleSheet(f"""
            QLabel {{
                border:none;
                font-size: {pt_size};
                color: #fff;
                background-color: transparent;
            }}
        """)
        self.container.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.container)

        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"windowOpacity")
        self.animation.setDuration(2000)  # Set the duration of the fade out animation
        self.animation.finished.connect(self.deleteLater)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(3000)  # Set the total display time of the message
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.fade_out)

    def show_message(self):
        self.setWindowOpacity(1.0)  # Set the initial opacity to fully visible
        self.show()
        self.timer.start()

    def fade_out(self):
        self.animation.setStartValue(1.0)
        self.animation.setEndValue(0.0)
        self.animation.start()

        self.timer.stop()

    def close(self):
        self.animation.stop()
        self.deleteLater()
class CustomButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.rect().contains(event.pos()):
            super().mousePressEvent(event)


class TransparentWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.Window)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        self.setup_ui()
        self.center_on_screen()
        self.active_window = None
        self.setWindowTitle('Mood Enhancer')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("pixel-heart.ico"))

    def setup_ui(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        title_bar = CustomTitleBar(self)
        layout.addWidget(title_bar)

        btn_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(btn_layout)

        btn_moods = ['sad', 'angry', 'neutral', 'happy', 'insecure', 'tired']
        self.setFixedWidth(160 * len(btn_moods))

        # Phrases to be considered for each button press
        self.mood_phrases = {
            'sad': ['You\'re so strong, this will go away soon enough, trust me.',
                    'You\'re not alone, we can get through this together.',
                    'Time for a good comeback story, let\'s get out there!'],
            'angry': ['21 - 22 - 23 - breathe, we\'re good.',
                      'Not everyone can be as utterly amazing as you are honey.',
                      'You\'re better than this, come on grab a coffee and\n a smoke and let\'s get cracking again.'],
            'neutral': ['It\'s a good day when you\'re here.',
                        'All the possibilities! How about you make someone smile today.',
                        'Believe in yourself and you can do anything \n you put your mind to.'],
            'happy': ['Keep shining, you beautiful, bright soul!',
                      'You have something in your face. \n '
                      'No, leave it, that smile looks amazing.',
                      'Reflect on where you started and how far you\'ve come,\n it\'s amazing you\'re here baby.'],
            'insecure': ['Listen, I know you can\'t understand this right now, \n but I love you any way you are.',
                         'Look in the mirror, you are absolutely beautiful today',
                         'Don\'t compare yourself to others, \n others could never compare to you'],
            'tired': ['Hope is good. Coffee is also good. Make your choice.',
                      'Reach out, we\'re here for you, promise',
                      'Everybody gets exhausted. Have some rest, it\'ll help.']
        }

        for entry in btn_moods:
            button = CustomButton(entry)
            button.setFixedWidth(150)
            button.setFixedHeight(60)
            button.clicked.connect(lambda checked, entry=entry: self.button_click(entry))

            # styling the button
            button.setStyleSheet(f"""
                            QPushButton {{
                                background-color: rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.7);
                                border: 5px solid rgba(107, 4, 102, 1);
                                border-radius: 10px;
                                color: #fff;
                                transition: background 1s;
                            }}
                            QPushButton:hover {{
                                background-color: #003366;
                            }}
                        """)
            btn_layout.addWidget(button)
        self.buttons_visible = True

        bottom_bar = QWidget(self)
        bottom_bar.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: rgba(107, 4, 102, 0.5);
            border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        """)
        bottom_bar.setFixedHeight(30)
        bottom_bar.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        layout.addWidget(bottom_bar)
        self.adjustSize()

        self.attached = False

    def attach_to_bottom(self):
        bottom_bar = self.layout().itemAt(2).widget()

        if not self.attached:
            bottom_bar.setFixedHeight(0)

            screen_geometry = QApplication.desktop().availableGeometry()
            screen_width = screen_geometry.width()
            window_width = self.width()
            x = (screen_width - window_width) // 2
            y = screen_geometry.bottom() - self.height() + 35
            self.move(x, y)

            self.attached = True
        else:
            bottom_bar.setFixedHeight(30)
            self.center_on_screen()

            self.attached = False


    def toggle_button_visibility(self):
        btn_layout = self.layout().itemAt(1)
        collapse_btn = self.window().findChildren(QPushButton)[1]
        bars = self.layout().itemAt(0).widget()

        if self.buttons_visible:
            for i in range(btn_layout.count()):
                btn_layout.itemAt(i).widget().setVisible(False)
                btn_layout.itemAt(i).widget().setFixedHeight(0)
            btn_layout.setSpacing(0)
            collapse_btn.setText("▲")

            if self.attached:
                screen_geometry = QApplication.desktop().availableGeometry()
                screen_width = screen_geometry.width()
                window_width = self.width()

                x = (screen_width - window_width) // 2
                y = screen_geometry.bottom() - (btn_layout.itemAt(i).widget().height() + (bars.height() * 2) - 10)
                self.move(x, y)

            #self.collapse_button.setText("▲")
            self.buttons_visible = False
        else:
            for i in range(btn_layout.count()):
                btn_layout.itemAt(i).widget().setVisible(True)
                btn_layout.itemAt(i).widget().setFixedHeight(60)
            btn_layout.setSpacing(6)
            collapse_btn.setText("▼")

            if self.attached:
                screen_geometry = QApplication.desktop().availableGeometry()
                screen_width = screen_geometry.width()
                window_width = self.width()

                x = (screen_width - window_width) // 2
                y = screen_geometry.bottom() - (bars.height() * 2) - btn_layout.itemAt(0).widget().height()
                self.move(x, y)

            #self.collapse_button.setText("▼")
            self.buttons_visible = True

        self.adjustSize()

    def center_on_screen(self):
        # Get the screen's geometry and move the window to the center
        screen_geometry = QApplication.desktop().availableGeometry()
        x = (screen_geometry.width() - self.width()) // 2
        y = (screen_geometry.height() - self.height()) // 2
        self.move(x, y)

    def button_click(self, entry):
        try:
            if self.active_window and self.active_window is not None and self.active_window.isVisible():
                self.active_window.close()
                self.active_window.deleteLater()
                self.active_window = None

        except Exception as e:
            traceback.print_exc()
            self.active_window = None

        finally:
            if entry in self.mood_phrases:
                phrases = self.mood_phrases[entry]
                msg = random.choice(phrases)
                if '\n' in msg:
                    window = MessageWindow(msg, '40px')
                else:
                    window = MessageWindow(msg, '50px')
                self.active_window = window  # Set the newly created window as the active window
                window.show_message()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QIcon("pixel-heart.ico"))

    window = TransparentWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And the command line I'm using:

`pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --icon=pixel-heart.ico main.py`

verified to be correct paths. I am not entirely sure where to upload the .ICO file or if it is necessary but if so, I appreciate directions.

Comment: replace the `=` by a space in the pyinstaller command. `pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --icon pixel-heart.ico main.py`

Comment: @mahkitah did this, same result overall - icon in the explorer, no icon in the tab/task bar

Comment: And you're 100% certain that the .ico file is in the working directory when the command is executed? Otherwise I'm out of options. It works fine for my own app with that command.

Comment: Explorer caches icons. What you're seeing might be a cached icon. Do you still see the icon in explorer when you use a different name for the program?

Comment: Yes, I am 100% certain and have double checked that the icon is in the same directory as the .py file i am exporting. And equally yes, if i name the file a completely random faceroll-type string i do still see the icon on it.

Comment: Check out [this tutorial](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/packaging-pyqt5-pyside2-applications-windows-pyinstaller/). The answer that worked for me (windows 10) was in the Taskbar Icons section. You might need to set an AppId for your application.

Answer (score 0):

By the link proveded by @Carl HR

Solved, due to my complete misunderstanding of how the pyinstaller packages the executable

The complete solution is that

- The paths need to be relative
- `windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)` This black magic line which overrides what Windows thinks your app is
- `pyinstaller --windowed --onefile --icon=pixel-heart.ico --add-data="pixel-heart.ico;." main.py` This export line, appending the --add-data field to carry the icon file over to the executable, which has to be done regardless of the --onefile policy applying or not

Massive Thank You to Carl HR for providing a solution, it has been days <3